# Magento-Auto login customer after confirming email

Tags: authentication, logging, magento

Is there a already existing solution to auto login customer after they confirm email? couldn't see such feature from admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

By just looking at the code (not testing), it seems that this is already the case.

1. When user clicks on the confirmation link in the email, it calls `\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Confirmation::execute`
2. This `execute` method does `$this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);` which calls `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session::setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn`
3. The `setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn` method is supposed to log the user

Perhaps is there some observer on `customer_login` and/or `customer_data_object_login` that  short-circuits this business logic.